# How can I get access token in keycloak?

Tags: keycloak, openid-connect, access-token

I want to login using authorization_code flow with keycloak.

I input correct username and password to login form, but I could NOT get tokens.

## my environment

- keycloak: docker with quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest(22.0.3-0) image
- OIDC client: PHP with Laravel server
- Cloud: AWS ECS(fargate)

## debug history

```
curl -s -X POST \
 -d "client_id=my-client" \
 -d "client_secret=kZseRPCrY2N2HXS0tlEdF1PRArzev1F1" \
 -d "username=test" \
 -d "password=test" \
 -d "grant_type=password" \
 -d "scope=openid" \
 "https://myprovider.example.com/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/token"
```

I got tokens!
so I think test user setting is correct.

next, I got authrorization code from Laravel server using step by step debugging.

my Laravel's first request like this:

```
curl -s -X GET "https://myprovider.example.com/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/auth?response_type=code&client_id=my-client&redirect_uri=https://myserver.com/path/to/callback&scope=openid"
```

I got code parameter from redirect_uri.

Like this: `1fca052c-7361-4d44-9659-0357aa61fc68.841308c9-8b38-4dc1-be45-30142e55d46d.551df351-b2dc-4059-9036-97a6a2007486`

next, I tried to change this code to tokens.

```
curl -s -X POST \
 -d "client_id=my-client" \
 -d "client_secret=kZseRPCrY2N2HXS0tlEdF1PRArzev1F1" \
 -d "grant_type=authorization_code" \
 -d "code=1fca052c-7361-4d44-9659-0357aa61fc68.841308c9-8b38-4dc1-be45-30142e55d46d.551df351-b2dc-4059-9036-97a6a2007486" \
 -d "redirect_uri=https://myserver.com/path/to/callback" \
 "https://myprovider.example.com/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/token"
```

I got:

```
<html>
<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>
</body>
</html>
```

other pattern:

```
curl -s -X POST \
 -d "client_id=my-client" \
 -d "client_secret=kZseRPCrY2N2HXS0tlEdF1PRArzev1F1" \
 -d "grant_type=authorization_code" \
 -d "code=expired_code" \
 -d "redirect_uri=https://myserver.com/path/to/callback" \
 "https://myprovider.example.com/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/token"
```

I got:

```
{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Code not valid"}
```

other pattern 2:

```
curl -s -X POST \
 -d "client_id=my-client" \
 -d "client_secret=kZseRPCrY2N2HXS0tlEdF1PRArzev1F1" \
 -d "grant_type=authorization_code" \
 -d "code=1fca052c-7361-4d44-9659-0357aa61fc68.841308c9-8b38-4dc1-be45-30142e55d46d.551df351-b2dc-4059-9036-97a6a2007486" \
 "https://myprovider.example.com/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/token"
```

I got:

```
{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Incorrect redirect_uri"}
```

I think JSON response is validation error, HTML 403 error is another error.

so I think validation process is passed, but it is failed because some setting is missed.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Where is code coming from?

Comment: sorry, I added history about this code.